# FFmpeg vaapi_transcode example executing error

Tags: c, ffmpeg, debian

(Sorry for my English)
I started to learn ffmpeg.
When I compiled and started vaapi_transcode.c a had a error `Failed to create a "VAAPI device. Error code: Cannot allocate memory`

I took this example from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/vaapi_transcode.c

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what is your issue, I will give you a few hints that at some point helped me.
Have you tried to use ffmpg executables with the same libs that you using when you run the app?
Have you check if you have the drivers working properly? 
I found this post which could help you:
[How do you get FFMPEG to encode with vaapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26000606/3673477)